# "Found the following calls to data() loading into the global environment"

Tags: r

In my R-package, I have:

```
f <- function()
{
    data('MyDataSet') # Load a dataset in my own package
    ... # Use MyDataSet to return something
}
```

The package builder has a warning message:

```
Found the following calls to data() loading into the global environment
```

What is the easiest way to fix the problem? Can I just load the data set into a variable? I don't need to save it to the global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CHECK**

I tested this and I could **built** the package without problems.

What gave me your note (not a warning, not a error) was actually performing the **check()** for the package.

**PROBLEM**

This is first of all important if you want to put the package on CRAN. Since the package will be very likely rejected if you do not have 0 notes, 0 warning, 0 errors.

If you just want to use the package for your own, you could also just leave it as it is. Since the check looks for coding guidelines and performs other useful things it indeed also may make sense to fix this for your private package.

**FIX**

One solution could be to include this dataset in your package itself.
You have to create a folder called **data** in your package to do this. Add the dataset as **.rda** file there. I think in your package description **LazyData: TRUE** has also to be set. (think this is the default).

Now you can write the following:

```
f <- function()
{
    x <- MyPackageName::MyDataSet
    ... # Use MyDataSet to return something
}
```